# Using Agent "Hosted VS2017" on VSTS yields error in test step

Tags: azure-pipelines, xunit.net

Up to now my build definition was configured as follows: `Default agent queue = Hosted` and in the Build Solution step `Visual Studio Version = Visual Studio 2015`. The build was running fine so far.

Now I am preparing to move to Visual Studio 2017 on my dev machine and I wanted to see if VSTS will then be able to still run my builds successfully.

I therefore switched to `Default agent queue = Hosted VS2017` and in the Build Solution step to `Visual Studio Version = Visual Studio 2017`.

Unfortunately I am getting the following error in the test assemblies step. I am using xUnit.net for my unit tests. I am not using .Net Core at the moment.

```
Finishing: Build solution $/tfs1/Apps/Base/Base.sln
********************************************************************
Starting: Test Assemblies **\debug\*test.dll;-:**\obj\**
********************************************************************
Task         : Visual Studio Test
Description  : Run tests with Visual Studio test runner
Version      : 1.0.84
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=624539)

Preparing task execution handler.
Executing the powershell script: C:\a\_tasks\VSTest_ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9\1.0.84\VSTest.ps1

No results found to publish.

System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: Unable to determine the location of vstest.console.exe ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to determine the location of vstest.console.exe
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.InvokeVSTestCmdlet.GetVsTestLocation()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.InvokeVSTestCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable input)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.ConstructPipelineAndDoWork(Runspace rs, Boolean performSyncInvoke)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.CreateRunspaceIfNeededAndDoWork(Runspace rsToUse, Boolean isSync)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvokeHelper[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvoke[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Handlers.LegacyVSTSPowerShellHost.VSTSPowerShellHost.Main(String[] args)

LegacyVSTSPowerShellHost.exe completed with return code: -1.
********************************************************************
Finishing: Test Assemblies **\debug\*test.dll;-:**\obj\**
```

Is VS2017 not yet fully supported at the moment in VSTS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change VSTest version to Latest for Visual Studio Test step/task.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the new build definition (Hosted VS2017 agent), you can use **.NET Core** task and **Publish Test Results** task to instead Visual Studio Test task. Detail settings as below:

#### .NET Core

Command: `test`

Project(s): specify the test csproj file(s), such as `**/*Tests/*.csproj`

Arguments: `--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)`

#### Publish Test Results

Test Result Format: `VSTest`

Test Results Files: `**/TEST-*.xml`

Comment: Does that imply that I have to develop with .Net Core only?

Comment: Yes, mostly. dotnet core project usually use .net core task. But there are still has other options, such as run `dotnet test` in comman line task etc.

Comment: But I must move away from using .Net 4.5.2 to .Net Core for all my projects that the build is to compile, correct?

Comment: Yes, it's used for .net core projects.

Comment: @David You can use .net framework with xunit test. Regarding your issue, you need to change VSTest version to latest (check my answer).